# How to set focus to a web control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Question:  What is the best way to set focus to a web control in ASP .NET.

I can do it, but it's ugly.  I have a web control wrapped in a web control hosted on a web page.  So, if you do a view | source on the page the id is something like WrapperControl_Control_TextBox.

I've tried the "tried and true" Javascript methods of grabbing the element and setting it's focus:  document.getElementByID( "WrapperControl_Control_TextBox" ).focus(); and it didn't work.  I'm not sure why.

I know I could possibly do:
document.getElementById( "<%= TextBox.ClientID %>" ).focus(); too, I think.  This won't work because of another totally separate error based on the fact you can't dynamically add controls to a header if there is a "<% %>" in the page.  GAH.

In the "bottom-most" control, I've tried setting the focus (TextBox.Focus() in Page_Load) and that doesn't work either.

Anyway, the way that works is by simply taking the ControlsCollection of the Page, grabbing the control I need from that, getting it's collection, grabbing the next lower control and so forth.

I only have to do this seven times.  So I have eight foreach loops.

Basically, my code is like this:

///////////////////////////////
// On the page
///////////////////////////////

```
ControlCollection controls = Controls;

foreach( Control control in controls)
{
   if ( string.Equals( control.ID, "FormID", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnore ) )
   {
      ControlCollection nextControls = control.Controls;

      foreach( Control nextControl in nextControls )
      {
         if ( string.Equals( nextControl.ID, "DivICareAboutInTheForm", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnor ) )
         {
             ControlCollection nextNextControls = nextControl.Controls;
             //:
             //:
             //Yes, it's that bad and so forth.
             //:
             //:
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do a search for IDs that end with your textbox name.  This way you wont have to call the UniqueID server-side code.  Just make sure not to have multiple controls that end with the same name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[id$=txtBox]').focus();
            });
    </script>
```

*Or*, you can use a Class name for the default text box.

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtBox" runat="server" cCssClass="defaultTextbox" />
```

jquery:

```
 $('.defaultTextbox').focus();
```

Comment: We don't have JQuery but I'll look into adding it.  Thanks.

Comment: I installed JQuery and rand your script.  It works!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the "cannot add dynamic controls because a <%= %> block exists on the page" error by changing the block to use databinding syntax: `<%# TextBox.ClientID %>`, and manually calling `Page.DataBind()` in Page_Load.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried the <%# %> trick but didn't know I needed to add the Page.DataBind().  I will look at that.  Thanks.

Comment: I did not try this since the JQuery solution mentioned above works, but I appreciate the help.  I may look into using this technique later.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the `Page_Load` method, then you could always call the [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e04ah0f4.aspx) method on the Page object.

```
Page.SetFocus(myTextBox);
```

Comment: I did not try this since the JQuery solution mentioned above works, but I appreciate the help.  I may look into using this technique later.